# How to avoid a 500 Internal Server Error when using the Rails ActionMailer on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to send an email to a user upon sign up in my web app, which is built with Rails in the back end and React-Redux on the front end. I used a gem called `letter_opener` when testing on a local server, and everything seemed to work fine. When I tried it live on Heroku, I got back a 500 error, and I'm not sure what is wrong.

I tried reading the ActionMailer docs, but it didn't seem to mention any issue like this.

The method in the UserMailer:

```
def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Welcome")
end
```

Relevant code in `UsersController`:

```
def create
   # ...
   email = UserMailer.welcome_email(@user)
   email.deliver_now   # This line throws the error
   # ...
end
```

The error from the Heroku logs:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):
```

I expected to the email to be delivered, or at least to have a more informative error message. I am not sure why Rails is looking at localhost's port 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris is right, Heroku doesn't provide an SMTP server and you've to use an Addon. I'll further add on how you can proceed with using [sendgrid](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sendgrid) addon which is free upto much extent.

First, goto your Heroku app -> Enable sendgrid addon. Then you'll be given sendgrid credentials. Keep them safe.

In your `config/environments/production.rb` add:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "your-domain.com", protocol: 'https' }
```

Then in your `config/environment.rb` file add:

```
...
# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

# Add sendgrid support
if Rails.env.production?
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => "sendgrid_username",
    :password => "sendgrid_password",
    :domain => "your-domain.com",
    :address => "sendgrid_hostname",
    :port => 3000, # sendgrid_port
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

Change the credentials above as required. Also consider using `ENV` variables for above credentials.

Comment: Thanks, this did it!

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure why Rails is looking at localhost's port 25.

ActionMailer [defaults to `localhost:25`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration), and you probably only changed your development configuration.

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25)

Heroku doesn't provide an SMTP server, and there certainly won't be one on `localhost`. Use [an email addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#email-sms) or some other third-party mail service of your choice.

You'll probably have to modify `config/environments/production.rb` to use whatever mail service you choose.